# C++ double pointer assignment

Tags: c++, double-pointer

Is there any difference between the following two assignment methods?

```
int * ptr1;
int ** ptr2;

//method 1
*ptr2 = ptr1;
//method 2
ptr2 = &ptr1;
```

Comment: See the dupe. The double pointers don't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
int* ptr; //declare a pointer
int** ptr2; //declare a pointer that will point to another pointer

*ptr2 = ptr; //dereferencing invalid address, undefined behaviour
ptr2 = &ptr; //makes ptr2 point to ptr
```

They are not the same!